# How can I disable animation when switching desktops in El Capitan?

Tags: macos

I would like to disable the switching animation when switching the desktop in mac os El Capitain. 
Do you know how to do that?

Thank!

Answer (score 5):

There is a program named **TotalSpace**, that has the feature you need. Once installed, you should open it up, go into "*Transitions*" and disable "*Use transitions*", this will remove the animation you get when you switch Workspace *(aka Dekstop)*

If you're on OS X 10.11.x El Capitan or later, you will also need to disable a feature known as "`System Integrity Protection`" which prevents you to edit or access system files. To disable it:

1. Restart the Mac, then boot it in recovery mode, by holding down `cmd` (or Windows key) and `R` keys, before hearing the sound of your Mac startup. Hold them down for 5 secs.
2. Click on "*Utilities*" on the top of your screen, then select terminal.
3. On the new opened window, enter `csrutil enable --without debug` .
4. Reboot
5. Enjoy :)

csrutil enable --without debug is the better solution suggested by [http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/elcapitan][totalspace].

Comment: Note: TotalSpaces2 versions 2.3.5 and above have support for El Cap but cannot run on a normally configured machine due to system integrity protection. See: http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/elcapitan

Comment: Well, not hard to disable it

Comment: Upvote still for the suggestion

Comment: Sure! AFAIK this is the best solution out there however imperfect.

Comment: Lemme update the answer

Comment: I wish I could downvote this, why would you advise people to disable System Integrity Protection?

Comment: @David天宇Wong after you made the change it can be reenabled